# Classic asp line number for err object

Tags: error-handling, asp-classic

In a classic asp script, I have a bunch of sql updates. If there were an sql-error, it was handled by a custom 500 error page, which logged the values of

```vb
    ' get the extended error information 
    Set ASPErr = Server.GetLastError() 

    strASPDesc = ASPErr.ASPDescription 
    strASPNumber = ASPErr.ASPCode 
    intASPLine = clng(ASPErr.Line) 
    intASPColumn = clng(ASPErr.Column) 
    strDesc = ASPErr.Description 
    strNumber = "0x" & Hex(ASPErr.Number) 
    strASPFile = ASPErr.File
    strERRline = ASPErr.Source
```

and logs this in to a sql-table. So it is easy to debug in case of errors. However, this could leave the database inconsistent, if some statements were executed, and other not.

So now I have wrapped it in a sub.

```vb
on error resume next
conn.beginTrans
do_transaction
if err.number=0 then
  conn.commitTrans
  response.write "OK"
else
  conn.rollbackTrans
  Response.write "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
  Response.write "Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf
end if
err.clear
on error goto 0

'here the actual transaction is done:
sub do_transaction
  set rs=conn.execute("SELECT ....")
  conn.execute("UPDATE ...")
  conn.execute("INSERT ...")
  conn.execute("DELETE ...")
end sub
```

This roll the entire transaction back if there is an error, however I now cannot see which statement caused the error.
The `Err` object does not contain line or column, and the `Server.GetLastError()` is not populated, except for a column 78, which does not make any sense at all.

Is there any way of getting what caused the error?
Can I get the sql-statement from the conn object?

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you can retrieve the sql statement in your error handling, but you could stick it in a variable, like `lastSql = "SELECT * FROM ..."` and then use that variable for error handling purposes, since it would always contain your last statement.